# 'Context' object has no attribute 'stdout_capture'

Tags: python, python-behave

I'm new to python and bdd and need some help, please. I'm trying to get junit reports from python behave, but after each test I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.4\helpers\pycharm\behave_runner.py", line 271, in <module>
_BehaveRunner(my_config, base_dir).run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.4\helpers\pycharm\_bdd_utils.py", line 96, in run
self._run_tests()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.4\helpers\pycharm\behave_runner.py", line 189, in _run_tests
self.__real_runner.run()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\behave\runner.py", line 672, in run
return self.run_with_paths()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\behave\runner.py", line 693, in run_with_paths
return self.run_model()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.4\helpers\pycharm\behave_runner.py", line 112, in run_model
return super(_RunnerWrapper, self).run_model(features)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\behave\runner.py", line 483, in run_model
failed = feature.run(self)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\behave\model.py", line 523, in run
failed = scenario.run(runner)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\behave\model.py", line 914, in run
self.stdout = runner.context.stdout_capture.getvalue()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\behave\runner.py", line 214, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError(msg)

  AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'stdout_capture'
```

By the way flags in behave.ini are next:

```
[behave]
junit=True
stdout_capture=True
stderr_capture=True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this. If you use ide to run test, as I do (PyCharm), then try to run it from command line and all should work fine.

Comment: How do you make it run inside the IDE ?

Comment: I didn't do that. I push my test to the repository and run it with Jenkins, so I get normal reports if I need. In IDE junit flag = False, because I always can see current results. If you need just run, then run any .feature file (http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2014/09/feature-spotlight-behavior-driven-development-in-pycharm/)

Comment: By the way, you need a Pro version of PyCharm, that already ready for use with Behave.